# How to enable browser cookies using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

Is there any way to enable browser cookies using Javascript? I need to show the user data in the form page which has filled by the user earlier. Please get me some solution to show the data which has already submitted before in the form page.

Comment: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/

Comment: Check http://www.wiziq.com/info/checkcookie.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done as it would bring security issues.